# How to calculating a MySQL articles size in Kb

Tags: php, mysql

I am trouble a problem. I want to know how to calculating my inserted Articles size in KB.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_post(cat,titile,body,author,tags) VALUES('$cat','$titile','$body','$author','$tags')";
```

This is my query and this is my blog site query.And I want to know how is my site articles size in KB as like show.

> $body

Size in kb.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Without any compression, just take the `strlen($body) / 1000`. You can also round the value up if you want with ceil().

Comment: I'm catching a whiff of Little Bobby Tables ...  https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's function `LENGTH()` in combination with `CONCAT()`. 
`LENGTH()` will return the column or SQL expressions (if it returns a string) length in bytes so you need to divide by 1000 to get Kb. 
Iám assuming your table has a id column.

```
SELECT 
   id
 , (LENGTH(CONCAT(cat,titile,body,author,tags)) / 1000) 'Size(Kb)'
FROM 
 tbl_post
WHERE 
 id = 1
```

**p.s if you want know the size directly after inserting you can use**

```
SELECT 
   id
 , (LENGTH(CONCAT(cat,titile,body,author,tags)) / 1000) 'Size(Kb)'
FROM 
 tbl_post
WHERE 
 id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
    $size = mb_strlen($body, '8bit') / 1000;
} else {
    $size = strlen($body) / 1000;
}
```